# Android change the pixel or the image size when saving to SQLITE

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I know this is quite common to ask but I'm really confused this time. All I need is to save the BLOB image to the SQLite and I have already done and saved it to SQLite, actually, I have two images saved as BLOB in SQLite I compared them but I really don't know the difference the other one contains `3000X4000 pixels 2.72 MIB` which much heavier size and the other one is much lighter which is `182x250 50.81Kib` and this is what I really want the `lightier size`. I upload two images to see what's really happening

Actually, I've been trying to develop Text Image Recognition. The image which bigger size sample, after capturing an image it should be crop and saves to SQLite while the lesser size just directly captured image and save to SQLite now they have the save function to save to SQLite I really don't know why they have different size and I think the problem is on the `crop` or `Pickcamera()`method which it changes the size of the image? is that possible?.

*The bigger one*

[image]

*The lesser one*

[image]

*The bigger size code Image* after clicking button it goes to `pickCamera()` method and the image display to the another activity

```
   public void pickCamera() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLER_CODE){
            CropImage.activity(data.getData()).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){

            CropImage.activity(image_uri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            resultUri.getPath();
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)mPreviewIv.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

            if(!recognizer.isOperational()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
                    TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
                    sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(ScanCashCard.this, ScannedDetails.class);

                //camera I want to display the image view to another Activity and save to SQLite

                i.putExtra("CashCardImage",image_uri.toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Display to another activity*

```
 String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage");
 Uri myUri = Uri.parse(resultUri);
 Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myUri);
 mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

*This code is from the lesser size*

```
public void pickcamera(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 101){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mPreview4PsId.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

*I think the problem is on the `pickCamera()` method which they different but when I follow the code from the lesser size the crop will not be available anymore, I stuck with this module anyone can help me? this is really help me a lot*

Answer (score 0):

So I just add a bunch of code which set and replace the default resolution of the Image pixel because I guess the default Pixel of the Image resolution from camera is `3000x4000 pixel` so you just need to set the width and height of the ImageView. So I just set `187x250`

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myUri);
mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 187, 250, false));
```